# Multiple Ubuntu installations in the same disk but different partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption

I need to install 3 different Ubuntus in different partititions and each installation shouldn't be able to read data from the others.

I thought this was simple installing multiple versions of Ubuntu in different encrypted partitions but I don't find how I can do this on the installer.
I tried creating partitions and I was able to install multiple Ubuntus in different partitions but I can't encrypt them so it is possible to mount the disks and read the data.

This setup is for security purposes so it is a must to avoid reading from one installation to the other.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If isolation is absolutely crucial, then partitioning is not going to do what you want. Realistically, there are just two options: (1) install on removable media, such as USB sticks (2) install via virtual machine. The first option offers the greatest degree of isolation, as some VM engines can be hacked to expose the host OS.

Comment: Why do you think that an encrypted partition is not good enough? I wouldn't like to run a VM in a potentially compromised OS because it can sniff OS operations.

Comment: You need to create a /boot partition that is a plain ext4 and grub will be kept in the first OS in the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a custom setup:

1. Install 1 of the OSs in an encrypted partition:

- Select 'Something else' option to create the partitions
- Create a small ext4 partition to mount /boot of 1gb
- Create the encrypted partition with the encryption option on creation
- When you see the partition all above as a virtual partition, select the one that has size and assign the '/' as mount point

2. Install the 2nd one on a encrypted using the same method of 1.
3. If you install another one, you will remove one of the others (I don't know why) so I recommend at this point:

- Install grub-customizer in the second installation (it will appear above in the boot menu).
- Save the partition settings of all the boot options you want to keep: select edit and copy all and store in a file in a pen drive.

3. Install the third installation following the idea of 1.
4. Boot the last installed OS that will be above.
5. Install grub-customizer in this OS.
6. You will have the last installed OS configured correctly and maybe the one installed before this, but you will not find the first installed. You have all the data you need to recreate the boot options in the pen drive so just do it.
7. Enjoy!